# Changing path/directory broke SSL certificate?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, subdomain

I ordered a 3-year SSL certificate for http://store.mywebsite.com, which has been working fine and great in all my testing. The site went live today and here's what is happening:

I am using a CMS for the store (Lemonstand), which dynamically generates pages with pretty URLS (mywebsite.com/store, for instance).

Before, in testing, I actually had the CMS installed in the directory /store, which the SSL cert is for. I moved the CMS directory to the root (I had be planning on this all along), and linked the store-related pages still to /store, but now they are dynamically generated and aren't real folders.

And now the SSL cert doesn't work. The subdomain doesn't work either.

Is there any way to configure this to work?

Comment: SSL certificates are tied to domains, not paths.

Comment: I believe that it's tied to the sub-domain store.mywebsite.com, so mywebsite.com/store doesn't get covered. Could you explain about the improperly setup DNS?

Comment: That is changing more than the path, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: So it seems I screwed up. Does it seem unreasonable that they wont let me switch the subdomain on the certificate? It's been about 40 days and it is a 3-year contract. I'm dealing with Domain Discover / Geotrust.

Comment: That's something you'll have to work out with the issuer :( The issuer would need to give out a new certificate, and they are out to make a $$$. If the entire site is the store, it might be "okay" to forward *.site.com to store.site.com as a work-about. Not the most pretty, but...

Comment: The solution was to point store.example.com at the root directory, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

If your certificate is for `store.website.com`, it isn't valid for `www.website.com` (or any subdomain besides 'store') unless it's a `*.website.com` certificate.

Comment: Before website.com/store was bound to store.website.com, but that was when /store was a real folder. Now it's dynamically generated. I'm getting a sinking feeling there's no way around this?

Comment: The directory structure on your server should be irrelevant to the URLs the certificate covers. Can you provide an example of a URL that was working and one that isn't now? For example: http://store.website.com/product-123 works but http://website.com/store/product-123 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You want a certificate with subjectAltName's covering both `mywebsite.com` and `store.mywebsite.com` for this kind of two-domain setup to work with a single certificate. The directory part of the URL is not relevant. `mywebsite.com` and `store.mywebsite.com` are distinct domains in the context of SSL/TLS in the Internet X.509 PKI.

Comment: The directory /store is store.mywebsite.com though - am I misunderstanding how this works? /public_html/store/index.htm would show up as store.mywebsite.com/index.htm

Comment: Relevant is only the URL the browser will see. How the web server maps the URL/URI to a file/directory or dynamically generated content, is irrelevant.